# What is wrong with my IF loops in a math checker?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm doing a math check for a video I watched where basically, you add Input1, Input2, Input3, Input4 together. If the sum is greater than 9, you take the integers and add them together and repeat and repeat until you have a single number of 1-9. You then take Input1 and do this digit addition until you get that single number less than 10. You repeat this for Input2, Input3 and Input4. Then you add these four numbers and repeat this digit addition with it until it also has a single number less than 10. The check is if the single number leftover from the sum of Input1,2,3,4 should be the same as the sum of digits of Input1,2,3,4 individually.

This works with small numbers, but with big numbers it doesn't. I get different numbers and numbers greater than 9 in the results.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 Input1 = 16836373683333
 Input2 = 2338737938763876373897
 Input3 = 3387398737837893
 Input4 = 48739873973334556368638637876383

 Sum = Input1 + Input2 + Input3 + Input4

 Sum = str(Sum)
 Sum = list(Sum)
 Sum = list(int(digit) for digit in Sum)
 Sum = sum(Sum)

 if Sum > 9:
     Sum = str(Sum)
     Sum = list(Sum)
     Sum = list(int(digit) for digit in Sum)
     Sum = sum(Sum)

 Input1 = str(Input1)
 Input1 = list(Input1)
 Input1 = list(int(digit) for digit in Input1)
 Input1 = sum(Input1)

 if Input1 > 9:
     Input1 = str(Input1)
     Input1 = list(Input1)
     Input1 = list(int(digit) for digit in Input1)
     Input1 = sum(Input1)

 Input2 = str(Input2)
 Input2 = list(Input2)
 Input2 = list(int(digit) for digit in Input2)
 Input2 = sum(Input2)

 if Input2 > 9:
     Input2 = str(Input2)
     Input2 = list(Input2)
     Input2 = list(int(digit) for digit in Input2)
     Input2 = sum(Input2)

 Input3 = str(Input3)
 Input3 = list(Input3)
 Input3 = list(int(digit) for digit in Input3)
 Input3 = sum(Input3)

 if Input3 > 9:
     Input3 = str(Input3)
     Input3 = list(Input3)
     Input3 = list(int(digit) for digit in Input3)
     Input3 = sum(Input3)

 Input4 = str(Input4)
 Input4 = list(Input4)
 Input4 = list(int(digit) for digit in Input4)
 Input4 = sum(Input4)

 if Input4 > 9:
     Input4 = str(Input4)
     Input4 = list(Input4)
     Input4 = list(int(digit) for digit in Input4)
     Input4 = sum(Input4)

 NewSum = Input1 + Input2 + Input3 + Input4

 if NewSum > 9:
     NewSum = str(NewSum)
     NewSum = list(NewSum)
     NewSum = list(int(digit) for digit in NewSum)
     NewSum = sum(NewSum)

 print Sum
 print NewSum
 if Sum == NewSum:
     print 'Checks out!'
 else:
     print 'Does not check out'
```

Comment: `if` is not a loop.

Comment: damn, so much copy/paste. I could write your code in 10 lines. At least it would be easier to debug.

Comment: If you want to loop for as long as each condition is true, replace the `if`s with `while`s.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for that! I'll never forget it mate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the main issue here (besides the horrible copy/paste thing) is that your `if x > 9` test is not within a *loop*.

So if some number is above 9, you reduce its value, but you're not making sure that it is not still above 9 (which explains that it works for small values).

My proposal (as said in comments, quite shorter :))

```
nums = [16836373683333, 2338737938763876373897, 3387398737837893, 48739873973334556368638637876383]

def onedigit(n):
    while n > 9:
        n = sum(int(x) for x in str(n))
    return n

print(onedigit(sum(nums)))
print(onedigit(sum(onedigit(x) for x in nums)))
```

I get 6 for both results. Checks out!